# File name containing zeros as same as file length

Tags: r

I am splitting pdf file into single pages R.But after when file gets generated the file name contains number of zeros same as length of file.So suppose my pdf file page of 10 then in file name it appends 10 zeros then serial number.So for small file its working fine but when i tried to split pdf containing 1000 or more then my code breaks because it first tries to append 1000 time zeros and then serial name.So Can any one help me on this.

Error while splitting file containing more than 800 pages

> Error in cpp_pdf_split(input, output, password) :    open
>   C:/Users/Desktop/Page
>   .pdf_00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001.pdf: No such file or directory

The following is my code:

```
install.packages("qpdf")
library(qpdf)
pdf_split(file.choose(),output = NULL)
```

I want my file name to be created only by page serial number, or a solution that will result in these unwanted zeros removed.

Comment: Why do you want this naming scheme

Comment: i need to process a file containing more than 25k pages so i want to name them seperately.e.g Page_1.pdf

Comment: Or you can suggest any name scheme that basically distinguish my entire file.Because its appending zeros same as total pages of file my code is not working for pdf containing more than 200-300 pages.

Comment: So why not do exactly as you suggest? Why do you need as many zeros as there are pages?

Comment: Like why do you want pdf_0001.pdf instead of something like pdf_somename_page3.pdf

Comment: i am not appending any zeros this pdf_split() function bydefault its appending zeros and i don't want this to happen.

Comment: pdf_somename_page3.pdf it will work for me

Comment: install.packages("qpdf")
library(qpdf)
pdf_split(file.choose(),output = NULL) if you will execute this code it will ask you to select pdf file that we neet to split and the moment you select the file it will save the output pdf file with name containing zeros.Is there any way by which i can provide my custom file name by using or adding lines to the existing code.

Comment: Oh I see now. Doesn't look like it.  Maybe make a feature request at their github page.

Comment: I understood your point but can you suggest any alternative i mean any other packages to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Nope. Best of luck - the package author probably would like to know about this though.  You should submit that feature request / bug report.

Comment: @Dason thank you so much for your help really appreciated 

Comment: Looking at the code base for qpdf I think it would be a relatively easy fix for the package author.  I think they'd just need to modify one line in particular.

Comment: @Dason yes exactly will raise bug on github

Comment: @Dason once again thank you so much for your efforts 

Comment: @Dason I figured out the solution with some other function from same package and its working fine

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.  Self-posting solutions is encouraged and can only help other people having a similar issue to you in the future.

Comment: @Dason Thanks for the suggestions.I have posted my solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(qpdf)
library(textreadr)

filePath <- file.choose()
pdfInputFile <- read_pdf(filePath)

for(i in 1:nrow(pdfInputFile))
{
pdf_subsets(filePath,pages = i,Output=paste0(gsub(basename(filePath),pattern=".pdf",replacement=""),"_",i,".pdf"))
}
```

Comment: this always crashes my computer even for small pdf's?